# Trying to implement a sliding progressbar without using gif

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a sliding progrees bar. I want the progress to gradually increase.

I try:

HTML

```
<div id="progressKeeper">
<div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#progressKeeper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 3px double #003366;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var el = $('#progress');
var steppedIncreaseAmount = ($('#progressKeeper').width()) / 100;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    el.width(el.width() + steppedIncreaseAmount+ 'px');
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbVBP/)

But it just increases suddenly. I want a smooth effect, like a fade.

Comment: Did you just want a static animation that isn't actually based on any progress check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set some kind of delay between the update of these values. However, because it appears that you're using jQuery, you can easily do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = $('#progress');
    el.animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 1800);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbVBP/2/

Another way, if you really want to keep the setup you've got going now, would be do just add a `setTimeout` counter to your for loop like this:

```
var el = $('#progress');
var steppedIncreaseAmount = ($('#progressKeeper').width()) / 100; 
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.width(el.width() + steppedIncreaseAmount+ 'px');
    }, 1+i*20);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbVBP/3/

Comment: You don't need to do that at all with jQuery animate.  Also with the animate, you can pass in "+=" + steppedIncreaceAmount and eliminate the need to access the width() again.

Comment: @CrazyBS I don't know what you're referring to. In my first example I don't use `width()` at all, I use `100%`.

Comment: I was referring to the second example.

Answer (score 2):

A simple for-loop is updating the values way faster than your eye can catch up....

You can use a timer function like `setInterval` for basic JS animation. This would work like:

```
var increase = setInterval(function(){

    el.width(el.width() + steppedIncreaseAmount+ 'px');

}, 50); //50 is the interval in ms, i.e the function inside the interval gets called 20 times per second
```

When you are done with the animation (progress is at 100%) you should cancel the interval:

```
clearInterval(increase);
```

See a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbVBP/1/) and [MDN docs on setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

If you want to dig deeper into the realms of JavaScript animation you might also want to learn about [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using animation:

```
el.animate({ width: "+=" + steppedIncreaseAmount }, 500);
```

Comment: This uses unnecessary variables

Answer (score 0):

Oh, don't use javascript for this. You can do it with only CSS3 animations.

```
@-webkit-keyframes progress { 
    from { }
    to { width: 100% }
}
```

And in progress bar:

```
-webkit-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
-moz-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
-ms-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VbVBP/4/

Answer (score 0):

I set up a demo of what I could figure out. http://jsfiddle.net/VbVBP/5/
I set the time of update to 300ms and the speed of that update animation to 300 also so it is constantly animating.

Instead of using the random value you would use whatever percentage complete your operation is.

```
<div id="progressKeeper">
<div id="progress"></div>
</div>​

var randomPercentInt = 0;

function percentComplete(percent) {
    var el = $('#progress');
    el.animate({
        width: percent
    }, 300);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    percentComplete('0%');
});

function randomPercent() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    randomPercentInt += randomNumber;
    console.log(randomPercentInt);
    if(randomPercentInt>100)
    {
        randomPercentInt = 100;
        clearInterval(clearme);
    }
    percentString = randomPercentInt.toString() + '%';
    percentComplete(percentString);
}
clearme = setInterval(randomPercent, 300);​
```